# How to assign NaN to tensor element?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to assign NaN to a tensor element.

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
x[x == 2] = None
```

I have the error `TypeError: can't assign a NoneType to a torch.LongTensor`.
I need it to make sure that some later sophisticated calculations are not made for certain values of x.

Comment: Please ask a consistent question: you say that you want to assign `Nan`, but your code specifically tries to assign `None`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following code will set the desired value to `nan`:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3]).float()
x[x == 2] = float('nan')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had never seen `float('nan')` before! Thanks for the other answer. To add up to it, I wanted to emphasize that there are different versions of `NaN`, defined in different packages. For example, `pandas` and `numpy` have multiple versions. I wanted to verify that they all represent a similar object.

The takeaways are:

1. Equality for torch tensors works, but not when they contain `nan`s,
2. All `nan`s can be used when checking for closeness of tensors.
3. All `nan`s can be used to create torch tensors. They are all compatible.

---

Here is the experiment:

```
import torch
import numpy

tensor_float_nan = torch.tensor([(float('nan'))])
tensor_np_nan = torch.tensor([(numpy.nan)])
tensor_np_nan_var = torch.tensor([(numpy.NaN)])
tensor_np_nan_again = torch.tensor([numpy.nan])

>>> print(f"Check if equality works for tensors:  "
          f"{(torch.tensor([1.]) == torch.tensor([1.])).item()}.")
True

>>> print(f"Check if float nan is the same as itself:  "
          f"{(tensor_float_nan == tensor_float_nan).item()}.")
False

>>> print(f"Check if float nan is the same as np nan: "
          f"{(tensor_float_nan == tensor_np_nan).item()}.")
False

>>> print(f"Check if float nan is the same as np nan var: "
          f"{(tensor_float_nan == tensor_np_nan_var).item()}.")
False

>>> print(f"Check if float nan is the same as np nan again: "
          f"{(tensor_float_nan == tensor_np_nan_again).item()}.")
False

>>> print(f"Check if np nan is the same as np nan var: "
          f"{(tensor_np_nan == tensor_np_nan_var).item()}.")
False

>>> print(f"Check if np nan is the same as np nan again: "
          f"{(tensor_np_nan == tensor_np_nan_again).item()}.")
False

>>> print(f"Check if np nan var is the same as np nan again: "
          f"{(tensor_np_nan_var == tensor_np_nan_again).item()}.")
False

>>> print(f"Check all close between float nan and np nan: "
      f"{torch.allclose(tensor_float_nan, tensor_np_nan, equal_nan=True)}.")
False

>>> print(f"Check all close between float nan and np nan var: "
      f"{torch.allclose(tensor_float_nan, tensor_np_nan_var, equal_nan=True)}.")
True

>>> print(f"Check all close between float nan and np nan again: "
      f"{torch.allclose(tensor_float_nan, tensor_np_nan_again, equal_nan=True)}.")
True

>>> print(f"Check all close between np nan and np nan var: "
      f"{torch.allclose(tensor_np_nan, tensor_np_nan_var, equal_nan=True)}.")
True

>>> print(f"Check all close between np nan and np nan again: "
      f"{torch.allclose(tensor_np_nan, tensor_np_nan_again, equal_nan=True)}.")
True

>>> print(f"Check all close between np nan var and np nan again: "
      f"{torch.allclose(tensor_np_nan_var, tensor_np_nan_again, equal_nan=True)}.")
True
```